# Accessing pgp encrypted file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pgp

I have a pgp-encrypted file that I need to extract data from at runtime.
Can this be done by decrypting to memory only (as opposed to creating a decrypted file and deleting it when done)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Ruby library called [OpenPGP](http://github.com/bendiken/openpgp/tree/master) was released a few months ago. It seems like it'd work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, most of the methods (e.g. sign(), verify(), encrypt(), and decrypt()) are not yet implemented (by the time of this writing) in the *OpenPGP* gem, which makes it useless.

I also found *gpgr* (https://github.com/HHRy/gpgr) not to be useful.

I am using *gpg-me* (https://github.com/ueno/ruby-gpgme/) for signing emails. At least for this purpose, it works fine.

I have not tried to decrypt files, but a short look at the source codes suggests that it will also work.